# Mapping nearest neighbours of a long-lat data set using ggmap, geom_point and a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, subset, ggmap

My ultimate goal is to connect all nearest neighbours of a set of buildings (based on Euclidean distance) on a ggmap using geom_path from the ggplot2 package. I need help with a loop that will allow me to plot all neighbours as easily as possible

I have created a distance matrix (called 'kmnew') in kilometres between 3 types of building in Beijing:  B (x2), D (x2) and L (x1):

```
   B        B        D        D        L
B NA 6.599014 5.758531 6.285787 3.770175
B NA       NA 7.141096 3.873296 5.092667
D NA       NA       NA 3.690725 2.563017
D NA       NA       NA       NA 2.832083
L NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

I try to discern the nearest neighbours of each building by row by declaring a matrix and using a loop to ascertain the nearest neighbour building:

```
nn <- matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=1)


for (i in 1:nrow(kmnew)){
  nn[i,] <- which.min(kmnew[i,]) 
}
```

This returns the following error (not sure why):

```
Error in nn[i, ] <- which.min(kmnew[i, ]) : replacement has length zero
```

but seems to return the correct answer to nn:

```
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    4
[3,]    5
[4,]    5
[5,]   NA
```

I append this to an original dataframe called newbjdata:

```
colbj <- cbind(newbjdata,nn)
```

that returns

```
  Name Store sqft     long      lat nn
1    B     1 1200 116.4579 39.93921  5
2    B     2  750 116.3811 39.93312  4
3    D     1  550 116.4417 39.88882  5
4    D     2  600 116.4022 39.90222  5
5    L     1 1000 116.4333 39.91100 NA
```

I then retrieve my map via ggmap:

```
bjgmap <- get_map(location = c(lon = 116.407395,lat = 39.904211),
                  zoom = 13, scale = "auto",
                  maptype = "roadmap",
                  messaging = FALSE, urlonly = FALSE,
                  filename = "ggmaptemp", crop = TRUE,
                  color = "bw",
                  source = "google", api_key)
```

My ultimate goal is to map the nearest neighbours together in a plot using geom_path from the ggplot package.

For example, the nn of the 1st building of type B (row 1) is the 1 building of type L (row 5). Obviously I can draw this line by subsetting the said 2 rows of the dataframe thus:

```
ggmap(bjgmap) +
geom_point(data = colbj, aes(x = long,y = lat, fill = factor(Name)),
           size =10, pch = 21, col = "white") +
geom_path(data = subset(colbj[c(1,5),]), aes(x = long,y = lat),col = "black")
```

However, I need a solution that works like a loop, and I can't figure out how one might achieve this, as I need to reference the nn column and refer that back to the long lat data n times. I can well believe that I am not using the most efficient method, so am open to alternatives. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by saying "the nn of the 1st building of type B (row 1) is the 1 building of type L (row 5)"? I do not understand this. How do you want to draw lines? Here you have 5 points in your map. What would you want in the end?

Comment: The nearest neighbour (nn) column of my data frame refers to which row the nearest neighbour is. So the nn (nearest neighbour) of row 1 (B store 1) is row 5 (L store 1). My goal is to connect all nearest neighbours by a line (geom_path), as I have connected these two manually in the minimum example, except in a more automated way than I have achieved using 'subset'. Many thanks!

Comment: That means you have one line going to somewhere from each data point. Is that correct?

Comment: Done. Hope the following is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I used `gcIntermediate()` from the `geosphere` package to set up lines. First, I needed to rearrange your data. When you use `gcIntermediate()`, you need departure and arrival long/lat. That is you need four columns. In order to arrange your data in this way, I used the `dplyr` package. `mutate_each(colbj, funs(.[nn]), vars = long:lat)` works for you to pick up desired arrival long/lat. `.` is for 'long' and 'lat'. `[nn]` is the vector index for the variables. Then, I employed `gcIntermediate()`. This creates SpatialLines. You need to make the object a SpatialLinesDataFrame. Then, you need to convert the output to "normal" data.frame. This step is essential so that `ggplot` can read your data. `fortify()` is doing the job.

```
library(ggmap)
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

### Arrange the data: set up departure and arrival long/lat

mutate_each(colbj, funs(.[nn]), vars = long:lat) %>%
rename(arr_long = vars1, arr_lat = vars2) %>%
filter(complete.cases(nn)) -> mydf

### Get line information

rts <- gcIntermediate(mydf[,c("long", "lat")],
                      mydf[,c("arr_long", "arr_lat")],
                      50,
                      breakAtDateLine = FALSE,
                      addStartEnd = TRUE,
                      sp = TRUE)

### Convert the routes to a data frame for ggplot use

rts <- as(rts, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")
rts.df <- fortify(rts)


### Get a map (borrowing the OP's code)                   
bjgmap <- get_map(location = c(lon = 116.407395,lat = 39.904211),
                  zoom = 13, scale = "auto",
                  maptype = "roadmap",
                  messaging = FALSE, urlonly = FALSE,
                  filename = "ggmaptemp", crop = TRUE,
                  color = "bw",
                  source = "google", api_key)

# Draw the map
ggmap(bjgmap) +
geom_point(data = colbj,aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = factor(Name)),
           size = 10,pch = 21, col = "white") +
geom_path(data = rts.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
          col = "black")
```

[image]

EDIT

If you want to do all data manipulation in one sequence, the following is one way to go. `foo` is identical to `rts.df` above.

```
mutate_each(colbj, funs(.[nn]), vars = long:lat) %>%
rename(arr_long = vars1, arr_lat = vars2) %>%
filter(complete.cases(nn)) %>%
do(fortify(as(gcIntermediate(.[,c("long", "lat")],
                          .[,c("arr_long", "arr_lat")],
                          50,
                          breakAtDateLine = FALSE,
                          addStartEnd = TRUE,
                          sp = TRUE), "SpatialLinesDataFrame"))) -> foo

identical(rts.df, foo)
#[1] TRUE
```

DATA

```
colbj <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("B", 
"D", "L"), class = "factor"), Store = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
sqft = c(1200L, 750L, 550L, 600L, 1000L), long = c(116.4579, 
116.3811, 116.4417, 116.4022, 116.4333), lat = c(39.93921, 
39.93312, 39.88882, 39.90222, 39.911), nn = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, NA)), .Names = c("Name", "Store", "sqft", "long", "lat", 
"nn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"))
```

Comment: That's exactly the result I was looking for. Many thanks for this, jazzurro. I'm not familiar with gcIntermediate, but looks like I should be. Will take me a while to get my head round it, but once again this is immensely helpful and above and beyond what I had expected. Thank you!

Comment: @RichS I am glad to hear that this is what you wanted. There may be other ways to do the same work. But, this is what I know based on my experience. I usually handle tasks drawing lines between two points in this way. Have a look of the CRAN manual of geosphere. Alternatively search other packaes. You may find shorter solutions. :)